# My class objects with randomised values get the exact same values

Tags: javascript, class, object, random

I'm trying to create multiple objects with different randomised values with a structure from a JSON file. For every new object I create I, for some reason, get the same randomised values as the first object.

I'm doing this by creating an object through a class. I put every "Thingy" created in an array for future reference.
The JSON file is populated with attributes that should, everytime a new Thingy is created, each get a random value from 0-10.
Classes is not my strong side, I'm happy to hear better ways to do this (I'm interested in having funtions inside the Thingies later on).

When I reload the page and create a new Thingy, by pressing my button, the values are beautifully randomised.
The problem is that every time I press my button to create more Thingies the name is randomised BUT every value gets the same random values as the previous Thingy.
At first I thought is was a problem with Javascript using a pseudo random number generator but now I believe I have some wrong understanding on a script language level.

Can anyone shine some light on what I'm doing wrong or not understanding?

Please tell me if I should provide any more information, this is my first post!

**CODE:**

```js
var i;
var names = ["bjorn", "agnetha", "benny", "annifrid"];
var thingies = [];

var jsonFile = {
  "bodyA": {
      "sub1": {
          "subsub1": null,
          "subsub2": null,
          "subsub3": null
      },
      "sub2": {
          "subsub1": null,
          "subsub2": null
      },
      "sub3": {
          "subsub1": {
              "subsubsub1": null,
              "subsubsub2": null,
              "subsubsub3": null
          }
      }
  },
  "bodyB": {
      "sub1": {
          "subsub1": null
      }
  },
  "bodyC": null
}

class Thingy {
  constructor (name, attributes) {
      this.name = name;
      this.attributes = attributes;
  }
}

var button = document.createElement("input");
  button.type = "button";
  button.value = "Create new thingy";
  button.onclick = function() {
      // I'm using the math.js to get a random value from the names array (Yes, in this debugging instance it could get the same name as other Thingies)
      thingy = new Thingy(math.pickRandom(names), getAttributes(jsonFile));
      thingies.push(thingy);
      console.log(thingy.name + " was created!");
  }
  document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(button);

function getAttributes(json) {
  function iterateObject(json) {
      Object.keys(json).forEach(function (k) {
          if (json[k] !== null && typeof json[k] === 'object') {
              iterateObject(json[k]);
              return;
          }
          if (json[k] === null) {
              // This is where I get the exact same values everytime I create a new Thingy after the first one
              json[k] = math.randomInt(0, 10); // (Also from math.js - very similiar to default Math)
          }
      });
      return json;
  }
  return iterateObject(json);
}

function logThingies() {
  for (i = 0; i < thingies.length; i++) console.log(thingies[i]);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- math.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/6.6.1/math.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <button onclick="logThingies()">Show me all!</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd advise you to try to make your question less diffuse; boil it down to just the key question, without all the back story if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are creating a random value only when `json[k] === null`, and then assigning that random value to `json[k]`, so `json[k]` will never be `null` again.

In JavaScript, all objects are passed/assigned by reference. That means that when you have an object and assign that object to another variable, or pass the object to another function as an argument, the variable/function will receive the same object that you passed, not a copy of it, and modifying the object received will modify the "base" object you passed to it, as is the same object.

Check this test:

```js
var obj = {
    test: 1
};

var obj2 = obj;

console.log("obj.test:", obj.test);
console.log("obj2.test:", obj2.test);

obj.test = 2;

console.log("obj.test:", obj.test);
console.log("obj2.test:", obj2.test);
```

In short, all your Thingies attributes are a reference to the same object placed in the same space of memory.

What you want to actually do is to create a copy of the object, for example, with something like this (I've just modified a bit your code):

```
function getAttributes(json) {
  var ret = {};
  function iterateObject(ret, json) {
      Object.keys(json).forEach(function (k) {
          if (json[k] !== null && typeof json[k] === 'object') {
              iterateObject(ret[k] = {}, json[k]);
          } else if (json[k] === null) {
              // This is where I get the exact same values everytime I create a new Thingy after the first one
              ret[k] = math.randomInt(0, 10); // (Also from math.js - very similiar to default Math)
          } else {
              ret[k] = json[k];
          }
      });
  }
  iterateObject(ret, json);
  return ret;
}
```

Note how I create a new object each time that `json[k]` is an object. This way you will always receive a new clean object without modifying `json`.

Comment: Expetionally fast answer! Thanks a bunch, this solved it.